# SQL Query to retrieve next available ID from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains a column called ticket_id and it contains values as follows:

```
ticket_id
STK0000000001
STK0000000002
STK0000000001
STK0000000003
STK0000000002
STK0000000001
```

The ticket_id value will repeat in certain rows, so it is not unique.

I am using this query to get the next available id, but I am not able to get it working. It always returns `STK0000000002`.

Any help is appreciated!

SQL:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('STK', LPAD(seq, 10, '0')) AS nextID
FROM
    (SELECT
        @seq:=@seq+1 AS seq,
        num
    FROM
        (SELECT
            CAST(SUBSTR(ticket_id, 4) AS UNSIGNED) AS num
        FROM
            sma_support_tickets
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(ticket_id, 4) AS UNSIGNED))+2 AS num
        FROM 
            sma_support_tickets
        ORDER BY
            num) AS ids
    CROSS JOIN 
        (SELECT @seq:=0) AS init 
    ) AS pairs
WHERE
    seq!=num
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Can you store the string separate from the integer?

Comment: Sure @Strawberry, the database is existing and I am helping with changes. This was built sometime ago.

Comment: If it always starts with `STK`, leave that out of the database entirely. Just put it in the UI if you want it.

Comment: @TheRealPapa: Suggest to define a new auto increment pk field and a token string column whose value is filled by a trigger on insert operations.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar but we have already a bunch of historical data in the table in this format. Thanks for the edit too.

Comment: Hi @Ravinder I prefer to work with the current layout without adding to it. It contains historical data. What am I missing in the query to return the next avail? Thanks!

Comment: What logic are you trying to implement? Are you just trying to increment the highest value? Your query seems a little overkill for that...

Comment: would the next available id be `STK0000000004` in this case?

Comment: Hi @Fabricator, yes it would be! Thanks

Comment: The subquery returns `nums`: 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5. The first one where `seq != num` is `seq = 2` because `num = 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something in your question, but it seems that this should do it:

```
SELECT CONCAT('STK', 
              LPAD(MAX(SUBSTRING(ticket_id, 4)) + 1, 
                   10, 
                   '0')
             ) 
FROM sma_support_tickets;
```

Comment: Hi @shmosel, you ROCK! Thanks! I was modifying someone else's work rather than looking at it from scratch... it is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Try:  This table must have one serial number or unique number or ID for the table for each row. Find out that unique number(primary key) through code and add 1 or increment that number, but not to the ticket_id as you are doing it now. so that it can move forward to next row.